# Retrieving custom reference from a case

Tags: soql, custom, reference

Our case definition contains a billion custom fields, and I appear to be fine SELECTing FieldName__c in an API call. But I want to get a field, Case_Assignee__c which is defined as a reference. Using it always says there is no such field despite it being in the describe for Case.

The field would be a user, just like Owner is, but Case_Assignee__c.Name fails along with any other permutation I can think of. So I guess I'm missing some key Salesforce magic knowledge. Any pointers?

Comment: More information is needed here. Please [edit] your question to add details. Showing us the query that you're trying to run would be the bare minimum. You should also copy/paste the entirety of the error message that you're getting (trying to shorten/paraphrase errors means that you are leaving out important information). Educated guess is that you're using `__c` instead of `__r` when you are trying to reference data on a related object. I.e. you should be using `My_Relationship_Field__r.Related_Field__c`.

Comment: Pow! Case_Assignee__r.Name was the magic format @DerekF, thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to query for data on other, related records (usually on a different SObject but you can have a lookup relationship between records of the same SObject), you need to change the `__c` of the relationship field to `__r`.

E.g.

```
SELECT
    Id, Name, CreatedDate,
    Special_Owner__r.Name
FROM
    Opportunity
```

That's true for any custom relationship field.

For *standard* relationship fields, the API name is usually of the form `<object name>Id`. E.g. `OpportunityId` on `OpportunityLineItem`, `OwnerId` on nearly all SObjects, etc...

For those, you'd just drop the "Id" part.

```
SELECT
    Id, Name,
    Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.StageName
FROM
    OpportunityLineItem
```

Do note that this is specific to child -> parent queries, i.e. traversing *upwards* in the relationship hierarchy. Querying downwards in the hierarchy (parent -> children) also needs you to use `__r`, but there's a bit more to it and that doesn't seem to be relevant to this particular question.

More detailed/thorough information can be found in the [Relationship Queries section of the SOQL/SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm).